# PigServer or PigRunner? Which is better?

Tags: apache-pig

I have written embedded pig program using PigServer class.But I come to know that we can also execute queries using PigRunner class.

**Can anyone tell which one is better? please Explain the reason as well.**

Answer (score 3):

PigRunner essentially presents the same interface as the command line program "pig" with the advantage that it can be called without going to the system shell and that it returns a PigStats objects. It is therefore convenient for running complete user supplied scripts.

PigServer however allows on-the-fly creation and registration of queries, and then programmatic iteration over the results. It therefore provides a much more flexible and complete interface to PIG.